# Python curve_fit multiple functions goodness of fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, curve

I'm working on a Python program to fit a curve to some resonance data. I am using SciPy curve_fit to calculate curve from a function but I am using a combination of Gaussian and Lorentzian curves. I am calculating the error in the parameters and the least squares for each combination but I am looking for a way to test the goodness of fit to find which combination is the best.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Comment: I see the sum of squared errors, where error is the difference between the data and function prediction at each point.  Min sum of squared errors is the best fit.

Comment: Hi, sometimes I get a fit that has very low sum of squares but the curve does not look smooth. It seems like the data has been overfitted.

Comment: Overfitting is indeed a problem.  Higher order functions tend to suffer from it.  Maybe you need a piecewise polynomial fit.  Can't tell without seeing your data and functions.

Comment: If you're worried about overfitting, try using information criteria like AIC or BIC that penalise the number of degrees of freedom in a model. They are often used as decision criteria for model selection.